# Ksh syntax error '=~'

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

```
read -p "The Process running for "$days" days continuously OK to kill this     process (y/N)? " -u 4 ok
     [[ "${ok}" =~ y ]] || continue
        echo "Killing $pid"
      kill -HUP "$pid"
        fi
```

This is the snippet of my script ,when i am executing this it shows like

```
 `=~' is not expected.
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: You are dropping out of quotes for `$days` there and probably shouldn't be. What version of ksh?

Comment: ksh version i dont know.but it takes from /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: What does `ksh --version` say?

Comment: The version of ksh is ksh93

Comment: Is this intended to be a `ksh` script? The `-p` option there looks like the `bash` `read -p` option not the `ksh` `read -p` option (since the `ksh` one claims to be for a spawned process to read from in the manual I can see). `=~` should work in ksh93 from the manual also so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your shebang line has `#!/bin/sh` and so you don't have access to the full `ksh` syntax.  If you do, `ksh93` does appear to support `[[ string =~ regex ]]` syntax, so there's something here which doesn't add up right.

Either way, there is a construct which works just as well in classic Bourne shell which you can use instead, with the added bonus that your script will be compatible to systems where `ksh` is not available.

You use `read -p <prompt>` but that is a Bashism; the `-p` option to `read` has a quite different meaning in `ksh93`.

```
printf 'Process ran for %i days continuously, OK to kill this? ' "$days"
read -u 4 ok
case $ok in [Yy]* ) ;; *) continue ;; esac
echo "Killing $pid"
kill -HUP "$pid"
```

Your code looked for `y` anywhere in the input but I restricted that to only examine the first character.

(Your code had erratic indentation and an unpaired `fi` which I omitted.)

Comment: +1 on @EtanReisner's observation that `read -p` is a Bashism.  Fixing that by splitting the prompt to a separate `echo` should be easy.

Comment: I used like this.But it is not waiting for my Y  and it shows like this
The process running for 11 days continuously OK to kill the process (y/n)?
checkdisk.sh[61]: read: 0403-039 No query process for pipe.

Comment: The `-u 4` implies you have set something up to read from file descriptor 4 in code you are not showing us; if you haven't, it's just wrong.

Comment: i used like exec 4<&0 so that it will take the input from stdout.but it is not waiting for my input.It just printing read: 0403-039 No query process for pipe this.

Comment: The error message is because `read -p` has a different meaning in `ksh`, namely, to read from a pipe. So you'll need to change that.

Comment: Updated answer to fix this and hopefully clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your ? is 'how to resolve' - tripleee's suggestion looks like a solution - simplify the code - try:

```
if [[ "${ok} == "y" ]]
```

I tried copying your code snippet and I get a different error. Time for D&C - simple ksh93 script testing '=~'